# Adding Arpack/Armadillo in Cmakelist

Tags: c++, cmake, armadillo, arpack

I'm struggling with adding the ARPACK in myCMakeLists (see below) file of which i construct my Qt-project under Mac-OSX. 
Note that i installed the Armadillo library via 'Macport' and it's recognized automatically by Qt without adding it in the CMakeList file. But since i'm using the Sparse-Decomposition function of Armadillo, Qt asks me to link the ARPACK library to the project. I installed the ARPACK library but i didn't find how to add  in my CMakeList file. How could i add it please ?

Answer (score 3):

I fixed this problems by adding thses lines to my CMakeList:

```
 SET(ARMADILLO_INCLUDE_DIR "/Users/Anass/Downloads/armadillo-  
 6.600.4/include/")
 SET(ARMADILLO_LIBRARIES "/Users/Anass/Downloads/armadillo-
 6.600.4/libarmadillo.6.60.4.dylib")
 SET(ARPACK_LIBRARIES "/opt/local/lib/libarpack.dylib")
 ...
 IF(LAPACK_FOUND)
    SET(LINK_LIBRARIES  
    ${LAPACK_LIBRARIES} ${BLAS_LIBRARIES}   
    ${ARMADILLO_LIBRARIES} ${ARPACK_LIBRARIES})

    ELSE()
    SET(LINK_LIBRARIES ${ARMADILLO_LIBRARIES} ${ARPACK_LIBRARIES})
    ENDIF()

   MESSAGE("")
   MESSAGE("STEP 3 : GENERATE COMPILATION PROCESS")
   MESSAGE("")

   include_directories(

        ${ARMADILLO_INCLUDE_DIR}
   )

   if(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX)
    message("adding c++11 support")
    list(APPEND CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++11 ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}")
  endif(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX)

   ########################################################
   SET(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ./bin)

   MESSAGE("Add test cmake")

   SET(test_cmake_SRCS
       ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/test_cmake.cpp


   )
   add_executable(test_cmake ${test_cmake_SRCS})
   target_link_libraries(test_cmake ${LINK_LIBRARIES})
```